# Mouse over in CommanNavigator

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In eclipse shrink size of  the Package explorer view.

Then keep the mouse over the packages then you can see a tool tip will show the entire package name. I am doing all these things in Winsows OS.

Do the same thing in Ubuntu OS tool tip is not showing. why?

**Why i am asking this**:

In my product i have created a package explorer view using CommonNavigator. this explorer is showing tool tip in Windows not in Ubuntu. i want to show tool tip in Ubuntu as well.

Note:I don't want to extend the CommonNavigator class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tool tip is done by the native code that SWT uses to draws the tree. On some platforms the native code show the tool tip, on others it doesn't. There isn't anything in the tree API to control this.